# Python requests header not working - Checked Chrome developer tools -> Network

Tags: python, python-requests

This is my python code:

```
import requests
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    url = 'https://google.co.in'
    headers = {
        'User-Agent':'blahblahblah'
    }
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    return 'check terminal'
```

So this is the way to change request headers in python requests. But if I open the url and see developer options > Network > Request headers. I see default as user agent. Means it simply doesn't work.

Comment: There are *two* requests here. You browser makes a request to the running Flask instance, and the Flask instance makes a 2nd request to Google's server. You are setting the user agent on the request which Flask makes to Google, but that doesn't do anything to change the original request which your browser made to Flask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request you're making is by the server, not the client (the web browser). The `index` page served by flask goes to a client. The client doesn't make the `requests.get` request you've written here, instead the server does.

Instead, the client only requests whatever you're returning from the route, which here is `'check terminal'` (which should not work, and should be something in the lines of `return jsonify(result='check terminal')`), and is not concerned about what the server is doing internally.

So as @brunns has commented, these two requests are different. If you want to check the headers of your request, maybe try [httpbin.org](https://httpbin.org/#/HTTP_Methods/get_get).

Comment: I checked server headers. It didn;t show that I am using that user agent string.

Comment: It won't show because it is not the request you're thinking it is.

Comment: Make a `get` request at [httpbin.org/get](https://httpbin.org/get).

Comment: Seems like it's working. But somehow the url has blocked my IP. Any workaround on this?

Comment: Hmmm. Weird. That URL should not block *any* IP. Can you share your code (in another question, or maybe in a [StackOverflow chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/))?

Comment: The actual URL is nseindia.com'

Comment: @TheOnlyAnil I think you should ask another question regarding this as I'm not very good in making blocked IPs working. (Maybe using proxies, but I am not sure).